# Replace `Page` with `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage`

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm attempting to use [Windows RT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) so that I can have access to the `TreeView` control. I've created a new BlankApp that contains a MainPage containing XAML similar to this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BlankApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I want to change this `Page` to an `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage`. I've modified the XAML to be:

```
<xc:AlternativePage
    x:Class="BlankApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xc="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</xc:AlternativePage>
```

And modified the MainPage class to extend `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage` rather than `Page`.

Now when I launch my app, It fails in the following statement:

```
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
```

I receive the "Failed to create initial page", but not more details.

So my questions would be:
1. How can I find out more details on why the `Navigate` call is failing? I tried adding `rootFrame.NavigationFailed += rootFrame_NavigationFailed;`, but the navigation failed event does not seem to be getting raised.
2. How can I properly use the `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage` page?

Comment: In the exceptions dialog (Ctrl-alt-E if using C# scheme), choose to break on any exception. Post the callstack you are seeing there.

Comment: @ShaharPrish I have it set to break on all exception. Nothing gets thrown until the `throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");` Thats why I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Please note that Windows Runtime ("WinRT") is *not* the same thing as Windows RT.  The former is a development architecture, while the latter is Windows 8 on tablets.

Comment: @Zenox: You are right. I should have read the code more closely.

Comment: Note that you don't need AlternativeFrame or AlternativePage to use the Treeview. These are there for page transition and preloading support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do the rest of the changes needed to use the alternative page?

Take a look at the sample code in the SDK. Specifically here:

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/379f4af0e5862131aea1992f6875180abeddbcb6#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class AppShell : UserControl
{
    public static AlternativeFrame Frame { get; private set; }

    public AppShell()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Frame = this.RootFrame;
        this.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof (MainPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure did not! I completely missed those when I was looking over the changes I need. once I put the AppShell in place its working. Thanks!