# Use WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am trying to use the alternative page. I have the same problem with [WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativePage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131740/replace-page-with-winrtxamltoolkit-controls-alternativepage). 
I add a AppShell : UserControl to my project but i can't navigate to the page. What else i must do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `AppShell` to use `AlternativePage`. You need the `AlternativeFrame`.

Comment: I want to navigate between pages with a transition effect, without the the use of a frame. Is it possible?

Comment: Pages need a frame for navigation. If you don't want to use a frame - you don't want a page. To use Alternative-Page/Frame - you just replace your regular Page/Frames with the Alternative- ones and specify which transitions you want to use. If you don't want to use my implementation - you'd need to find or implement another. You can use the regular `Frame` and `Page` if you want. You would need to handle the transition yourself too - maybe create one that only display one page at a time or use `RenderTargetBitmap` to transition showing two at a time. You'll need to extend `Navigate()` too.